# Elastic search - get last second changes

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I get all changes that were indexed in my Elasticsearch cluster within the last second?
I've tried to add a time stamp and query it, but indexing some of the items took few seconds, and therefore these items were missing in the result (I didn't get them in the next second either, since the timestamp refers to the start of the indexing process).

Comment: You are aware of this, right? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm aware of that. I'm not concerned about the delay - getting all items that were indexed 2 secs ago is fine as well. I just want to detect all items that were indexed in the Elasticsearch, without lossing any one.

Comment: You should be able to access them via the translog. See [here][1] for more info.


  [1]: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/index-modules-translog.html